# Unable to parse value in <p> tags with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the values and the headers for the below tags. My first loop was to grab the  for specific attri and I was able to retrieve into a list. I need to be able to get the header column and the value. I think I need to have a nested loop after I get the paragraph, but I'm running into issues.

```
for row in table:
row = row.find('p')
print(row)

<p>
<strong>Retail Price:</strong>$48.99  
<strong>Sale Price:</strong>$26.42   
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to find the header column and then use next_element

```
import re

html = '''<p>
        <strong>Retail Price:</strong>$48.99  
        <strong>Sale Price:</strong>$26.42   
        </p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('strong', text=re.compile('Retail Price:')).next_element + " " + soup.find('strong', text=re.compile(
    'Retail Price:')).next_element.next_element)
print(soup.find('strong', text=re.compile('Sale Price:')).next_element + " " + soup.find('strong', text=re.compile(
    'Sale Price:')).next_element.next_element)
```

---

Or get the text of p tag and then split().

```
html='''<p>
<strong>Retail Price:</strong>$48.99  
<strong>Sale Price:</strong>$26.42   
</p>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.find('p').text.strip().split('\n'))
```